# SpaceX Canaveral launch question

Tags: spacex, launch

In the past, I could see space shuttle launches from my front door on the gulf coast of Pinellas County by looking due east on a clear day or night. I have tried to catch SpaceX launches a couple times, but could not see vapor trail or anything. Is the downrange trajectory for SpaceX such that my view is no longer possible from sea level on the beaches?

Comment: May be harder to see because of no SRB plumes.